# Uninstalling software using PowerShell on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I am using this script to uninstall software (eg. Java). However, I have two Java packages, Java 8 Update and Java Auto Updater, on my machine.

I understand that when I run my script on such a machine that has two software that match my Regex (`Java*` in this case), it fails to make a `$classkey` that is unique to remote machine's WMI and so is the case it breaks.

```
function Uninstall-Application($computer, $target) {
    $productInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%$target%'" -ComputerName $computer
    $pin = $productInfo.IdentifyingNumber
    $pn = $productInfo.Name
    $pv = $productInfo.Version

    if ($pn -ne $null) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Productinfo.length; $i++) {
            $classKey = "IdentifyingNumber=`"$pin[$i]`",Name=`"$pn[$i]`",version=`"$pv[$i]`""
            $uninstallReturn = ([wmi]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Product.$classKey").uninstall()
            if ($uninstallReturn.ReturnValue -ge 0) { Write-Host "Uninstall complete"}
            else { $uninstallReturn | Out-Host }
        } 
    }
    else {
        Throw "Product not found"
    }
}

uninstall-application "RemoteServer" "Java"
```

This code works, If there is just one software that matches my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to run the uninstall code against multiple items.

```
$products = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%$target%'" -ComputerName $computer
foreach ($productInfo in $products) {
    #uninstall code
}
```

Full function:

```
function Uninstall-Application($computer, $target) {
    $products = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%$target%'" -ComputerName $computer
    foreach ($productInfo in $products) {
        $pin = $productInfo.IdentifyingNumber
        $pn = $productInfo.Name
        $pv = $productInfo.Version

        if ($pn -ne $null) {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Productinfo.length; $i++) {
                $classKey = "IdentifyingNumber=`"$pin[$i]`",Name=`"$pn[$i]`",version=`"$pv[$i]`""
                #$uninstallReturn = ([wmi]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Product.$classKey").uninstall()
                #if($uninstallReturn.ReturnValue -ge 0) { Write-Host "Uninstall complete"}
                #else { $uninstallReturn | Out-Host }
            } 
        }
        else {
            Throw "Product not found"
        }
    }
}

Uninstall-Application "localhost" "Java"
```

Comment: OK, so uncomment the three lines to make the uninstall works?

Comment: Yep, there's no `-WhatIf` for that WMI command so I left it commented out.